# Focus control in a frame

Tags: delphi, interface

I hope I can explain wich is the prblem i'm trying to solve.
I've a form with 3 papnels: 1 for buttons, 1 for data, and 1 for messages. The data panel is populated with some frames (one for each database table I need to use).
The table detail frame and another used to display the record in a grid are manipulated with an interface.

Here the grid frame:

```
unit FraEdtList;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids;

type
  TFraEdtLst = class(TFrame)
    grdEditori: TDBGrid;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses database;

end.
```

and here the detail frame:

```
unit FraEdtDetail;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Mask, Vcl.DBCtrls;

type
  TFraEdtDtl = class(TFrame)
    lblIdEditore: TLabel;
    edtIdEditore: TDBEdit;
    lblDscEditore: TLabel;
    edtDscEditore: TDBEdit;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses database;

{ TFraEdtDtl }


{ TFraEdtDtl }

end.
```

Here is the interface unit:

```
unit Editori;

interface

uses
  FraEdtList, FraEdtDetail;

type
  IEditori = interface
    procedure CreateFraEdtLst();
    procedure CreateFraEdtDtl();
  end;

  TEditori = class(TInterfacedObject, IEditori)
  private
    FEdtLst: TfraEdtLst;
    FEdtDtl: TfraEdtDtl;
    procedure CreateFraEdtLst();
    procedure CreateFraEdtDtl();
  end;

implementation

{ TAutori }

uses Tabelle;

procedure TEditori.CreateFraEdtLst;
begin
  FEdtLst := FEdtLst.Create(frmTabelle);
  FEdtLst.Parent := frmTabelle.pnlDta;
end;

procedure TEditori.CreateFraEdtDtl;
begin
  FEdtDtl := TfraEdtDtl.Create(frmTabelle);
  FEdtDtl.Parent := frmTabelle.pnlDta;
end;

end.
```

I've added the "Editori" unit to the form that will use the frames.
For this example I've not used the grid, but only the detail frame and when the user select a table the records are shows as the following sample:

[image]

For example the first button (that with a blank paper) is used for insert a new record in my database table, the second one is used for edit the current shown record and so on.

The proble is tha I would like to focus the DBEdit component when the user click the "new" button or the "Edit" button, but I can't reach a way to do this kind of operation.

Here is the source of the for tha use the two frames (and some others)

```
unit Tabelle;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, RzPanel, dxBevel, Vcl.Buttons, PngSpeedButton, Autori,
  Editori, DBInterface, DbImplementation, MSAccess;

type
  TfrmTabelle = class(TForm)
    pnlCmd: TRzPanel;
    pnlDta: TRzPanel;
    pnlMsg: TRzPanel;
    bvlCmd: TdxBevel;
    bvlNav: TdxBevel;
    btnNew: TPngSpeedButton;
    btnEdit: TPngSpeedButton;
    btnSave: TPngSpeedButton;
    btnDelete: TPngSpeedButton;
    btnUndo: TPngSpeedButton;
    btnPrior: TPngSpeedButton;
    btnNext: TPngSpeedButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnNewClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnPriorClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnEditClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnUndoClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FDBTable: IDBTable;
    FAutori: IAutori;
    FEditori: IEditori;
  public
    procedure SetButtonsStatus(stsNew, stsEdit, stsSave, stsDelete, stsUndo, stsPnlDta: Boolean);
    procedure SetTableName(Table: TMSTable);
  end;

var
  frmTabelle: TfrmTabelle;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TfrmTabelle }

{ Inizializzazione }
procedure TfrmTabelle.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDBTable := TDBtable.Create;
end;

{ Impostazione tabella di lavoro }
procedure TfrmTabelle.SetTableName(Table: TMSTable);
begin
  FDBTable.DBTable := Table;
  SetButtonsStatus(True, True, False, True, False, False);

  // Tabella autori
  if Table.TableName = 'Autori' then begin
    if not Assigned(FAutori) then begin
      FAutori := TAutori.Create;
      FAutori.CreateFraAutDtl;
    end;
  end;

  // Tabella editori
  if Table.TableName = 'Editori' then begin
    if not Assigned(FEditori) then begin
      FEditori := TEditori.Create;
      FEditori.CreateFraEdtDtl;
    end;
  end;

end;

{ Impostazione pulsanti }
procedure TfrmTabelle.SetButtonsStatus(stsNew, stsEdit, stsSave, stsDelete, stsUndo, stsPnlDta: Boolean);
var
  flgTblEmpty: Boolean;
begin
  flgTblEmpty := FDBTable.TableIsEmpty;
  btnNew.Enabled := stsNew;
  btnEdit.Enabled := stsEdit and not flgTblEmpty;
  btnSave.Enabled := stsSave;
  btnDelete.Enabled := stsDelete and not flgTblEmpty;
  btnUndo.Enabled := stsUndo;
  pnlDta.Enabled := stsPnlDta;
end;

{ Inserimento nuovo record }
procedure TfrmTabelle.btnNewClick(Sender: TObject);

begin
  if FDBTable.NewRecord then
    SetButtonsStatus(False, False, True, False, True, True);
end;

{ Editazione record }
procedure TfrmTabelle.btnEditClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FDBTable.EditRecord then
    SetButtonsStatus(False, False, True, False, True, True);
end;

{ Salvataggio record }
procedure TfrmTabelle.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FDBTable.SaveRecord then
    SetButtonsStatus(True, True, False, True, False, False);
end;

{ Cancellazione record }
procedure TfrmTabelle.btnDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FDBTable.DeleteRecord then
    SetButtonsStatus(True, True, False, True, False, False);
end;

{ Annulla l'operazione in corso }
procedure TfrmTabelle.btnUndoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FDBTable.UndoRecord then
    SetButtonsStatus(True, True, False, True, False, False);
end;



{ Record precedente }
procedure TfrmTabelle.btnPriorClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FDBTable.PriorRecord then
    SetButtonsStatus(True, True, False, True, False, False);
end;

{ Record successivo }
procedure TfrmTabelle.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDBTable.NextRecord;
end;

end.
```

As you can see in the above code also the database is used via an interface!
I hope I was clear in my explication, but I know the question is a bit complicate to tell.
Can, please, someone help me?

Comment: What's wrong with using either `edtIdEditore.SetFocus;` or `ActiveControl := edIdEditore;`?

Comment: The ptroblem is that the edtIdEditore control is in a frame wich is controlled by an interface and the form "tabelle" doesn't know the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface IEditori need to be expanded to give the outer controlling form a way to inform the interface what is needed.  For example the interface could have methods like AddingRecord, SavingRecord, ValidateRecord, etc.  The parent form then does not need to know about individual controls on the Frame, but the frame can be told what is happening and react correctly by setting the focused control. There may be other things you want to do a new record like defaulting values or setting a additional state.

You can sometimes figure things out by handling events directly from the Table such as OnNewRecord, but when you are passing a table around you need to make sure you don't step on events that were set elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

For example, to give focus to `edtIdEditore` when the user click the `btnEdit` do the following:

```
{ Editazione record }
procedure TfrmTabelle.btnEditClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FDBTable.EditRecord then
    SetButtonsStatus(False, False, True, False, True, True);
  frmTabelle.edtIdEditore.SetFocus;
end;
```

Or replace `frmTabelle` with the name of the form instance exposed in the `var` section of your unit then add the unit to your `uses` clause and you're done.